# How to recover accidentally deleted /etc/rc.d file or folder?? What is the impact of deleting them?

Tags: linux, rhel, rm, rc

I am relatively new to black-screen Os-es (unix/linux)

Version:
Linux version 2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64 
(mockbuild@x86-027.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) 
(gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) ) 
1 SMP Wed Oct 26 10:25:23 EDT 2016

I was given few commands to run on Linux:

remove etc/rc.d/rc0.d remove only logscan, procscan and gpp

I got confused and did: (a) rm -rf rc.d and (b) rm -rf rc0.d   but as a result rc, init.d, rc1.d, rc2.d, rc3.d, rc4.d, rc5.d, rc6.d, rc.local, rc.sysint files/folders also got deleted.

Later, I copied the rc.d folder from another server but there are several softlinks and the whole folder structure was lost, no softlinks but only files were there. a day later those files were also got deleted automatically.

What is the impact or effects of removing /etc/rc.d and /etc/rc0.d? How is it related to the init.d file? Can we restore these files (rc.d & rc0.d)? Can we copy them from another server and place them under /etc? Will that help? Does restarting help? is there any option to restore the files/folders back??

Please Please help.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli can u please help here?

Comment: I merely removed a wrong tag from the question. I don't know how to solve your problem.